# Repeating questions to user ten times in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

I want to write a program for a simple maths test. I want to generate two random numbers and have users enter the sum of these two numbers. I know how to do this but I want the program to present the question ten times and then will display how many calculations out of ten the user got correct. I can't work out how to repeat the question without writing it out again and again in code! Please could you tell me if this has anything to do with for loops or is there another way this can be done? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you studied loops yet? I'd use a `for` loop.

```
for _ in range(10):
    number1 = # not sure how you're
    number2 = # generating your numbers
    answer = int(input(str(number1)+str(number2)+"= ..."))
    # you may want to do something different here in case the user
    # enters a non-integer, e.g. "I don't know" which will currently
    # error out your code with a ValueError
    if answer == number1+number2:
        # Handle correct answer
    else:
        # Handle incorrect answer
```

Note that the `_` in `for _ in range(10)` isn't a special character, it's just a commonly-used idiom among programmers to say "I need to assign this value to a variable, but I don't actually have to use the value, so disregard." In this case, `_` is `0`, then `1`, then `2` etc all the way to `9`, but since we never have to USE those numbers anywhere, we just assign it to `_` to tell the coder who has to maintain our work "Don't pay attention to this."

Here's a possible way that you can handle the user input:

```
for _ in range(10):
    # generate number1 and number2 here

    validated = False
    while not validated:
        try:
            answer = int(input("your input prompt goes here"))
            validated = True # your code will error before here
        except ValueError:
            print("Your answer must be an integer")

    # the rest of your code
```

Comment: @user3356798 I updated my code with a more reasonable solution to handling user input. It was silly to run `isinstance` each time, I must have been smoking glue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the for loops is the way to go.
Here is a basic code that do what you asked:

```
from random import randint

NB_QUESTIONS = 1


correct = 0
for _ in range(NB_QUESTIONS):
    rand1 = randint(0, 10)
    rand2 = randint(0, 10)
    answer = raw_input("What's the sum of %d + %d? " % (rand1, rand2))
    answer = int(answer)
    if answer == rand1 + rand2:
        correct += 1
print 'You got %d/%d correct answers' % (correct, NB_QUESTIONS)
```

The raw_input function take on argument: the prompt (what will be print on the screen) [see doc](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input)
The function return a string so you need to convert it to an int before using it
The last step is to check if the result is good or not, if it is good add 1 to the number of correct answer.
Finish the program by print the number of correct answers.